# Close the request in serverconnect function

Tags: mitmproxy

I want to implement the shielded IP address function in `mitmproxy`. In order to get the server address, I chose to implement the function in the `serverconnect` function, but I found that I couldn't close the request normally. I tried to use `conn.finish()`, but although the `socket` is closed, there is still an action to write to the `socket`.
This is my important code:

```py
class ReservedAddress:
    ...
    def serverconnect(self, conn: mitmproxy.connections.ServerConnection):
        if self._is_reserved_ip_addr(conn.ip_address[0]):
            conn.finish()
    ...
```

I don't know how I should do it, please help me. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! I think you can get a better response by explaining a bit about what mitmproxy is (or include a link). Also, if you want a specific answer to your problem it would be nice to recreate the problem with a bit of working code. Anyway, I've reviewed https://docs.mitmproxy.org/ and wondering if the ignore_hosts option will work for you. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, but using `ignore_hosts` does not solve my problem. I want to prohibit some people from accessing my intranet resources through my open proxy.